# Move SKSpriteNode until touches ended

Tags: xcode, swift

I created this game in Spite Kit in Swift. I create a ship that I can determine its location be touching above or underneath the location of the ship. The ship will move towards the Y axis where I placed my finger. However at this point the ship will only move by a specific amount, in this case 30 or -30. How can I rewrite this code so the ship will keep on moving until my release of my finger?

Thanks!

```
func addShip() {
    // Initializing spaceship node
    ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship")
    ship.setScale(0.45)
    ship.zRotation = CGFloat(-M_PI/2)

    // Adding SpriteKit physics body for collision detection
    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ship.size)
    ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(shipCategory)
    ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ship.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
    //NEWLY ADDED
    ship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = coinCategory

    ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    ship.name = "ship"
    ship.position = CGPointMake(120, 160)

    self.addChild(ship)

    actionMoveUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 30, duration: 0.2)
    actionMoveDown = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -30, duration: 0.2)
}
```

Comment: The title sends when "touches ended" but you say in here you want the ship to continue moving after your hand is released, correct?

Comment: Just a debug thing, both `actionMoveUp` and `actionMoveDown` are `moveByX` functions. Was that intended? As for continuous movement, consider using forces and velocity instead of skactions. Actions are intended to manipulate the look of a node on the screen and to add visual effects, whereas physics options such as Velocity, Force, Impulses, etc. were added for the purpose required. I can offer code in Objective-C, but the general implementation would be to add a physicsBody to ship (you did that), add a force when touch is present, and set the velocity to a <0,0> vector when touch ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't like to use SKActions for these types of things because they're really meant for one off simple animations..  However, it may be appropriate depending your game's requirements..

if you insist on using SKActions then instead of doing `moveBy`, why don't you just use `moveTo` utilizing touch location?  The only thing you'd have to do is come up with a ratio based on the distance your sprite needs to travel so that your animation duration is correct.  example:

```
let curPoint = self.sprite.position
let destinationPoint = touch.position

let diffPoint = CGPoint(
    x: curPoint.x - destinationPoint.x,
    y: curPoint.y - destinationPoint.y
)

let distance = sqrt(pow(diffPoint.x, 2) + pow(diffPoint.y, 2))

let durationRatio = distance / CGFloat(600)

let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(point, duration: NSTimeInterval(durationRatio))

self.sprite.runAction(moveAction, withKey: "move")
```

then when you want to cancel the movement.  in `touchesEnded` you do

```
self.sprite.removeActionForKey("move")
```

**using physics velocity**

```
let curPoint = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
let destinationPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

let diffPoint = CGPoint(
    x: curPoint.x - destinationPoint.x,
    y: curPoint.y - destinationPoint.y
)

let distance = sqrt(pow(diffPoint.x, 2) + pow(diffPoint.y, 2))

let normalizedVector = CGPoint(
    x: diffPoint.x / distance,
    y: diffPoint.y / distance
)

let speed = CGFloat(100)

let velocity = CGVector(
    dx: normalizedVector.x * speed,
    dy: normalizedVector.y * speed
)

self.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity = velocity
```

in touchesEnded you do

```
self.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation. Would you be willing to show how to do this using physics options as well? I agree that SKAction might not always be the best pick for this, unfortunately I haven't found another better way to get the result I want. I appreciate you guys taking the time to help me out! Also, for some reason "point" in moveAction is giving me an error.

Comment: Awesome, I just saw your update. Thank you so much. If for some reason I chose to only move ship up or down on the y-axis, what would I need to do in order to disable the x-axis move so the ship just moves up and down?

Comment: It depends if you're using velocity or actions. In the case of actions set x to the ships current x position. In the case of velocity x needs to be set to 0